# F# Remove Duplicates

Tags: list, recursion, f#

I'm trying to remove duplicates in a list with this function. It removes the duplicates, but returns the list in a reverse order. I'm a bit unsure how to fix that without an ugly solution.

Comment: Use `foldback`?

Comment: Dont know what that is.

Comment: inner lambda in `removeDuplicates` should be named `func` or `add` but stay the same along the code ; that said, you just have to reverse the resulting list either using `List.rev` or writing your own.

Comment: @Sehnsucht What would such reverse function look like?

Comment: @alexanderson `let rev xs = let rec aux acc = function [] -> acc | x :: xs -> aux (x :: acc) xs in aux [] xs`

Comment: You can just use do `[] -> List.rev nlist`

Answer (score 3):

There are already other answers that show various practical solutions to this, but I suppose you are interested in a minimal change to make your code work. When using accumulator in functional programming, you often end up reversing the list along the way - the standard solution to this is to reverse the list at the end, which you can do using `List.rev`:

```
let rd list= 
   let rec func list nlist=
      match list with
      | [] -> List.rev nlist // Reverse the list before returning it
      | x::xs ->
         if not (isMember x nlist) then 
            func xs (x::nlist)
         else
            func xs nlist
   func list []
```

Aside from adding `List.rev`, I also changed the last line to `func list []` (your code had `add` there, but this probably was a typo). I also changed `isMember x nlist <> true` to more idiomatic `not (isMember x nlist)`.

Comment: could be even more idiomatic to just invert `if` and `else` block and drop the `not`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to remove duplicates:

```
Seq.distinct [1;1;2;4;4;5;6]
```

It returns [1;2;4;5;6]

Comment: That's not really the practice im going for >.<

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me how much help (or lack of it) you want from standard library functions in your solution.

The simplest approach is just to use `List.distinct`

> ```
> List.distinct [1;1;2;4;4;5;6];;
> val it : int list = [1; 2; 4; 5; 6]
> ```

You could make a version using `foldBack`

```
let distinct lst = 
    List.foldBack (fun v lst' -> 
        if List.contains v lst' then lst'
        else v::lst') lst []
```

This produces the same result:

> ```
> distinct [1;1;2;4;4;5;6];;
> val it : int list = [1; 2; 4; 5; 6]
> ```

If you want to make your own `foldBack` too...

```
let rec foldBack f lst z =
    match lst with
    |[] -> z
    |x::xs -> f x (foldBack f xs z)
```

Notice that I'm trying not to write one big function that does everything and am instead trying to build a solution from a series of reusable components - this is a good habit to get into when working in functional languages.